# Squid Proxy Bloquea escritorio remoto

Tags: proxy, iptables

Les planteo mi escenario de la siguiente manera

[image: Escenario montado]

Creo mis reglas de bloqueo dentro del squid proxy para bloquear paginas y puertos. Y mi problema es que cuando me quiero conectar a un escritorio remoto de windows mediante ip, este no me conecta agregue la ip y el puerto y me sigue sin conectar.
Entonces leyendo vi que esto podria ser una solucion tiene que crear una iptabla el cual rediriga el trafico al puerto que usa el RDP hacia el proxy y estoy haciendo esto

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INTERFAZ_LAN -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination $SQUID_SERVER_IP
```

Voy por buen camino o me podrian orientar que es lo que podria intentar

Comment: Hola! Te faltó decirnos cuál es el problema con esto. ¿A qué te estás conectando? Cóµo es la arquitectura de red por la que pasas para llegar a ese recurso? QUé tiene que ver ahí Squid? NO creas ninguna iptabla, creas una regla en iptables para permitir el tráfico por esa interfaz de red y a ese puerto de destino. Por favor, ve a [edit] y explica con más detalle el problema

Comment: Hola
Gracias por tu comentario, ya explique un poco mas como esta el asunto

Comment: Tambien leí esto:
Squid maneja solicitudes y respuestas de protocolos web como HTTP y HTTPS, squid no esta diseñado para manejar otros tipos de tráfico, como el tráfico del protocolo de escritorio remoto (RDP) que utiliza el puerto 3389.

El tráfico RDP es un protocolo completamente diferente al HTTP y HTTPS, y normalmente no se maneja a través de un proxy web como Squid. Squid generalmente no es capaz de inspeccionar y reenviar el tráfico RDP de la misma manera que hace con el tráfico HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: En efecto, Squid es un proxy de tráfico web con funcionalidades orientadas a ello. Creo que vas a ser mucho más feliz si intentas usar HAProxy

Comment: Entonces podria montar un servidor con squid proxy para que me maneje las solicitudes http/https  para hacer filtrado y control de acceso e instalar en ese mismo servidor HAProxy para menejar el trafico del protocolo de escritorio remoto o crear una iptable para que me redireccione el trafico al puerto que usa RDP?

Comment: Yo diría que sí :) HAProxy es muy configurable. iptables sólo define qué pasa, qué no y por qué interfaz de red sale/entra. Si necesitas proxy/proxy reverso, no es con iptables